# Return error code to to client in the same request when user click button in the returned view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I am developing a payment gateway using asp.net mvc/web api which can be integrated with any client(web,windows,android etc).

I created a controller action which returns a page for user to enter the payment details. Its works fine.

The client only calls this action and enters the details.if submit is clicked then it will process the payment, cancel is clicked an error code should be returned and client redirect to other pages based on the error code.

I call this in my web application using ajax and when the page is returned the request completes.

My question is how the client receives the error code in the call back of the same service when user click submit or cancel? Is there any way to accomplish this because client doesnt need to call an extra request for this?

This is my client code

```
    function loadPage() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:55015/payment/CardPayment/CardPayment/username/andhZ25lck9UUw==/password/MTIz/PGPW/testpwd",
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: "multipart/form-data",
        data: xmlToSend,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#resultView').html(response);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: post the code you have tried from your side

Comment: post the code in your question rather than in comment. that would be better to read

Comment: I added my client code which call the controller action and load the page. I want to receive response here when user click  cancel button in my view

Comment: i think response from server will have error code, if any. just you need to check that attribute in response!

Comment: But after the view is returned how the same call back can be hit without making no extra call??